# For an event, I'm using a price set - how do I check that everyone has selected some ticket type before they are status "registered"?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

We're using a CiviRule to send tickets out to everyone with Status Registered (so if someone says pay later, they don't get their tickets until they pay) but when we're testing I can not select a ticket type and still get a ticket by email. We will also have some free tickets through CiviDiscount, so adding a minimum payment doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make the price set required, which will mean they have to select an option before they can continue.

Comment: Thanks Jenni - I came to that a few minutes after posting - we've got an event where we're selling both tickets and tables and sponsorships - I've split them out to two "events" - one for the people and one for the sponsors/table buyers (we didn't want to make the sponsors or table purchasers to also have to buy a single ticket).